# Part of text invisible in Codemirror

Tags: javascript, refresh, codemirror

I use Codemirror and set it up with this (with the latest version of Google Chrome):

```html
<script>
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    mode: 'markdown',
    autoRefresh:true,
    lineNumbers: false,
    lineWrapping: true,
    theme: "default",
    extraKeys: {"Enter": "newlineAndIndentContinueMarkdownList"},
  });
</script>
```

**The problem is that a part of the text is not visible before I scroll or edit the text.**

### 1. editor.refresh() fails

Because my div containing the textarea is not visible from the start I call `editor.refresh();`. Before no text was visible.

### 2. setTimeout fails

I also tried this trick without any luck:

```html
setTimeout(function() {
    editor.refresh();
},1);
```

### 3. autoRefresh fails

I also tried the `autoRefresh` plugin but that did not do any difference.

Below is an animated screenshot where you can see what is happening.

### Some more information

The `pre` with `CodeMirror-line` class is not rendered. It's not just hidden, it's not even there. I guess Codemirror tries to be smart and render on demand?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** There's been a response to this question over here https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/part-of-text-not-rendered/2030/5 The solution that worked was to specify the option `viewportMargin: Infinity`.

I had a problem like this and it was ultimately caused by incorrect CSS layout on my part, outside of CodeMirror. Try inspecting the CodeMirror element, and checking its height. The height should be within the display, not off the display. When I had a similar problem, the height of the CodeMirror instance was larger than the display. I corrected it by ensuring a height of 100% for all divs that ultimately contain the CodeMirror instance.